# wp-admin will not redirect to wp-login.php

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, login

For some reason my plugin is causing the `/wp-admin/` to not redirect to `wp-login.php` as it should. I've narrowed it down to these two lines of code:

```
foreach( glob($this->path['modules_dir'] . '*/_*.php') as $class_path )
    require_once( $class_path );
```

I'm not sure if its the `glob()` function or what, but locally this is not an issue but once live on hosting it is an issue. The host is using `PHP Version 5.4.20` and its is [A2 Hosting](http://a2hosting.com/) in case those details help.

If there is anything else that can help leave a comment and I'll add. This is very frustrating because there is nothing in error logs or anywhere that would suggest an issue, it just simply doesn't work

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

**Background**

**The Div Library plugin** is library that I'm developing, it is an activated plugin that essentially doesn't do anything except make an extended library of functionality available for developers to use when creating custom solutions for projects, you can review the [git repo](https://github.com/DivTruth/div-library/), but essentially it is instantiated like this:

```
if(class_exists('div_library')){
    return $library = div_library::instance(); #singleton
}
```

Then at the end of construction it fires the action:

```
// Div Library loading complete
do_action( 'divlibrary_loaded', $this );
```

After this, in the `mu-plugins` a developer would create their custom business logic for the site using the classes available from Div Library (optional). **[Div Starter](https://github.com/DivTruth/div-starter)** is the companion to the library, it is a child-like boilerplate for developing with Div Library and it auto-loads the add-ons and modules (CPT build-outs) using this `glob()` method as you can see. I've never had a problem till now, and even now it is only on A2 hosting that it appears. Hope that helps fill in any blanks

Comment: What happens instead of the redirect? (I assume you mean the core redirect when non logged in users try to get to admin pages) How is this code hooked in? Post it in more context please.

Comment: Yes when not logged in it just remains on /wp-admin/ as a blank page. The code base is [here](https://github.com/DivTruth/div-starter/blob/master/div-starter.php#L208) if that helps. This is in `mu-plugins` hooked to an action from the [Div Library plugin](https://github.com/DivTruth/div-library/blob/master/div-library.php#L290) on the `divlibrary_loaded` action. (NOTE: Div Library isn't hooked anywhere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the good news is I found the answer, the bad news is the answer is so lame. Apparently I have some ACF Field export files with multiple field groups each wrapped in their own `<?php ?>` wrapper. Well there was a line break between the two like so:

```
?>

<?php
```

And that was enough to break every thing. Lame right? So if you come across this check for white spaces or look for a way to have your host not be so picky about them :P